# How do we check if a bot is in your discord server with another bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a personal discord bot, and I wanted to add a feature in which it detects whether a particular bot is in the server or not.

Here's what I have

```
if(!message.guild.args[0] )
```

where the `args[0]` being the bot id

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Collection#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) on `message.guild.members` but this only includes chached members, so you should use [`Guild#fetchMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMember) and the then use `.then` and `.catch`